how to pass special characters to shell script using command line, without single quote or \
I have below shell script test.sh
#!/bin/bash
var=$1
echo $var

It gives un-expected output unless I pass command line argument value $-123 in single quote
#./test.sh  $-123
himBH123

#./test.sh  '$-123'
#$-123


I want to pass special character  $-123 to this script.
I know usual way is to pass it in single quote like '$-123' or backlash \
e.g.
test.sh '$123'

OR
test.sh \$123

Is there anyway to solve this by any change inside shell script.
So that user can pass ./test.sh  $-123 without single quote.
Reason I am asking is, in real time, we are passing multiple arguments to our script. Out of that one argument will be having password which will have this special character.
So just mentioning to pass only particular argument inside single quote '' and rest without any single quote will look strange or there are huge chances that customer might miss to pass single quote.

No. If it's a password, prompt the user for it and read it from the tty, don't take it as an argument.

@oguzismail this password is encrypted password which we will be passing. and also its 38 character length so will be difficult to pass, user, will pass it in script and run that script on 100 of server for automation, we can not pass as tty

"solve this by any change inside shell script": No. parameter expansion is done by bash before the script reads it. Quoting is a shell best practice so better teach that to users.

Don't put characters that need to be quoted in the password then. What you want is not possible in bash.

ok thanks @LMC for confirmation. This answers, basically I wanted to confirm if there is any other way.

Thanks @oguzismail for confirming, as I wanted to double check if there is any other way apart from command line passing. Thanks for confirming.

It's not just not possible in bash, it's not possible in any language whatsoever. No matter what language you implement test.sh in -- even if it's really a C program -- it gets arguments as they were parsed by the parent shell.

That said, you really shouldn't be putting passwords on the command line. pwhash='$123' test.sh (all one command line) is safer -- it puts the hash in the environment where only other processes owned by the same user (or by root) can see it, vs on the command line where it's readable by every process on the entire system.

(mind, the above assertion is true on UNIXlike platforms; Windows is different -- there command-line parsing is done within the program being called, and an application can override the usual libc-provided logic -- but you'd need to patch bash itself to make that true for shell scripts, and that patched version of bash would of course be Windows-only).

tl;dr
The most common, and quickest/easiest to consistently implement, is probably
read -rsp 'Please enter the "FooThingy" application password: ' pw
to let them type it in when asked.

You are using bash, so I'm writing this with some bash-isms. Be advised.

Is there a way to solve this by any change inside the shell script so that users can pass ./test.sh  $-123 without single quotes?

You're going to have to refactor your design, but that's basically what you were asking, yes? This is something of an X/Y Problem where you've asked for a solution to what you were trying to do rather than a way to get the result you wanted, which I assume is to get the correct password value into a variable for the program to use.
The short answer is no, your script can't let users arbitrarily pass special characters as CLI arguments without quotes this way, because the interpreter will already have mangled your data by the time the script sees it, but you shouldn't be putting passwords on the CLI this way anyway.
The longer answer is it depends, so let's look at a few options.
Quote your data.
First, quote your variables. What if the password is the Magic Word? What if instead of just spaces, it has a tab and a newline in it? The embedded spaces will make it three (3) separate arguments on the CLI, so the user would have to quote it anyway, and inside your program you might successfully assign their quoted $1 to var, but then if you use $var unquoted it separates it again. Just make a habit of always quoting your variables unless you have an actual, functional reason not to do so...and then you should be suspicious of your reason.
To demonstrate some of the differences:
#!/bin/bash
echo "Number of arguments passed: $#"
printf '[%s]\n' "$@"
echo "Without quotes:"
var=$1
echo $var
echo "With quotes:"
var="$1"
echo "$var"

Passing my password unquoted:
$: ./test.sh the Magic Word
Number of arguments passed: 3
[the]
[Magic]
[Word]
Without quotes:
the
With quotes:
the

Without quoting I can't even put the tab and newline in doing it this way.
With some quoting, look at the difference to what happens inside the script:
$: ./test.sh $'the\tMagic\nWord'
Number of arguments passed: 1
[the    Magic
Word]
Without quotes:
the Magic Word
With quotes:
the Magic
Word


Now that we've handled that, on to some solution options, but...
==>> Don't put passwords on the CLI.
This is just generally bad design. Most people won't take the precautions to keep it from going into their history file, people will see it over their (real or virtual) shoulder, etc.
Some alternatives:
Environment Variables
This is still not great, but it's a lot better.
Have the user set the value in an exported environment variable your script uses as needed. This can be done in their ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile (or equivalent), on their CLI, or ephemerally inline at runtime, which (even though they are still typing it in...) at least differentiates it enough they won't be confused.
Worst option: An "ephemeral" leading variable is set only for the scope of the single program execution, but it (probably) still goes into the history buffer. Still, since it comes before the script, anyone using it should be able to understand this is the thing that needs the quotes.
To demonstrate:
#!/bin/bash
echo "Number of arguments passed: $#"
echo "Password was: '$envpw'; argument list was:"
printf '[%s]\n' "$@"

In use:
$: envpw=$'the\tMagic\nWord' ./test.sh foo bar
Number of arguments passed: 2
Password was: 'the  Magic
Word'; argument list was:
[foo]
[bar]

Now the password in in my history file, but it works like a champ and isn't confusing. The down side is that if they fumble-finger a little and mistype the variable name, even with something like capitalization, it fails, and you have no simple way to accommodate that.
$: envPw=$'the\tMagic\nWord' ./test.sh foo bar
Number of arguments passed: 2
Password was: ''; argument list was:
[foo]
[bar]

(But a mistype is always a problem; YMMV.)
This also works with a pre-exported variable.
It does have to be exported:
$: envpw=$'the\tMagic\nWord'; ./test.sh foo 
Number of arguments passed: 1
Password was: ''; argument list was:
[foo]

$: export envpw=$'the\tMagic\nWord'
$: ./test.sh foo bar baz
Number of arguments passed: 3
Password was: 'the      Magic
Word'; argument list was:
[foo]
[bar]
[baz]

As stated before, a user can put the export in their profile, which should be permissions-restricted, and they may never have to type the password again - it will "just work".
Read from the Console
A popular option is to prompt the user and let them type the password directly into the program. While someone looking over your shoulder might see it this way, it doesn't leave it lying around in your history or your profile.
The simplistic version (we'll do better below):
$: cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Number of arguments passed: $#"
printf 'Please enter the password: '; read -r pw
echo "Password was: '$pw'; argument list was:"
printf '[%s]\n' "$@"

Now if I run it, it asks for the password.
$: ./test.sh foo
Number of arguments passed: 1
Please enter the password: the Magic    Word of $-123
Password was: 'the Magic    Word of $-123'; argument list was:
[foo]

This works pretty well; you can see it accepted embedded the tab between Magic and Word, and had no trouble at all with $-123, though it does make it tricky to put in the embedded newline I used before.
If your version of read has it, you can at least hide the input, and if it can do that you can probably make the prompt string part of the read statement, which is a little more concise.
This time I even threw in single quotes and an exclamation point into the password -
$: cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Number of arguments passed: $#"
read -rsp 'Please enter the password: ' pw
printf "\nPassword was: [%s];\nargument list was:\n" "$pw"
printf '[%s]\n' "$@"

$: ./test.sh foo
Number of arguments passed: 1
Please enter the password:
Password was: [tab:'    ' and $-123 Again!];
argument list was:
[foo]

And if you really want to allow that embedded newline in a password (honestly, I wouldn't, but...)
$: cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Number of arguments passed: $#"
read -rs -d $'\x04' -p 'Please enter the password (CTRL_D to submit): ' pw
printf "\nPassword was: [%s]; argument list was:\n" "$pw"
printf '[%s]\n' "$@"

$: ./test.sh foo
Number of arguments passed: 1
Please enter the password (CTRL_D to submit):
Password was: [the      Magic
Word]; argument list was:
[foo]

(Assumes a "normal" console configuration, but again, YMMV.)
Read from a File
This again leaves the password lying in a file, but the file can be permissions restricted, in a restricted path.
A simplest example:
$: cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
read -r pw < /tmp/foo/pwfile
printf "Password: [%s]\n" "$pw"

$: ./test.sh
Password: [$-123]

With just a little tweaking, you can have a standard file, but allow a user to override the default a simple env var -
$: cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
printf "Password: [%s]\n" "$(<${passfile:=/tmp/foo/pwfile})"

$: ./test.sh
Password: [$-123]

$: passfile=otherFile ./test.sh
Password: [the  Magic
Word!]

Note that the "$(<${passfile:=/tmp/foo/pwfile})" passes back the entire content of whatever file passfile names, including any trailing newlines, AS the password.
For bonus points, use GPG or OpenSSL to encrypt the password on disk, and decrypt into a variable inside your program when you need it.


Is there anyway to solve this by any change inside shell script. So
that user can pass ./test.sh  $-123 without single quote.

Actually, it is impossible in this way because shell will perform all this variable expansion, wildcard expansion, etc, before calling the script.
It is how shell works - parses command line, and then executes it, so the script will receive already expanded value.
So if you want to send anything to script as argument, you must put it in quotes.
In the script you can use "read" command to read something interactively, in this case you can pass anything without quotes

As others have already pointed out, no, there is no way within a command to let the caller of the command not use appropriate quoting as by the time your command sees it, the shell has already processed the arguments to then pass the results of that processing to your command.
Regarding "and rest without any single quote" - you're thinking of this backwards. In shell quotes aren't something you add when you need to, they're something you remove when you need to. Every string should be enclosed in single quotes by default. Change those to double quotes if you need to, e.g. to let variables expand, and change them to no quotes if you need to, e.g. to perform globbing, word splitting, etc. So you shouldn't tell your customers to add quotes around specific arguments, you should tell them to put single quotes around every argument unless they need to.
Having said that, if you think "there are huge chances that customer might miss to pass single quote" then you're saying they can't be trusted to use shell correctly and so instead of allowing them to pass arguments to your command you should have them provide data on stdin which your command then reads without the shell getting involved in interpreting their data before your command sees it. Consider instead of letting them call your commands directly, create a higher level command "shell" for them which they call first and that puts them into an environment where they can then call your lower level commands, e.g. let's say you currently have scripts named foo and bar that your customers call, instead you could do:
$ cat cmdenv
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo() {
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$FUNCNAME" "$*"
}

bar() {
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$FUNCNAME" "$*"
}

while read -p 'cmd> ' -r cmd args; do
    "$cmd" "$args"
done


$ ./cmdenv
cmd> foo $-123 $PWD
foo: $-123 $PWD
cmd> bar $(date)
bar: $(date)

So your customer calls cmdenv and then instead of calling foo from a shell, your customer would be "calling" foo from your while-read loop and so no shell would be interpreting it's arguments.
You'd have to enhance that to handle non-existent commands being called and how to parse the args to treat quoted strings as single values but neither of those are hard to do and it solves the problem you were asking about of how to not require your customers to understand shell quoting. If they wanted to do something that required variable name expansion or globbing then of course they'd have to do that in the shell and copy/paste the result into where they call foo in your command execution environment.

"they're something you remove when you need to." -- so much this. :)
